# Can I get state/information of an "Updating" Service Fabric cluster?

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-service-fabric, azure-rm-template

I have created a new Service Fabric cluster in Azure via ARM template, and this works fine. But now if I switch to the Azure portal, I get in the "Overview" only the information "Updating".

I use the Service Fabric version: 6.4.637.9590.

In the "Activity log" is written only "Create or Update Cluster" for 2 hours. Now it looks to me as if there are some issues, but I don't know where I can get more information.

Is there a way I can get some deploy / create information via Azure CLI?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the health information for a Service Fabric cluster by using [Get-ServiceFabricClusterHealth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/get-servicefabricclusterhealth?view=azureservicefabricps) command. Service Fabric reports the following health states:

- OK. The entity meets health guidelines.
- Error. The entity does not meet health guidelines.
- Warning. The entity meets health guidelines but experienced some issue.

You can also use Service Fabric Explorer to visualize your cluster. [Service Fabric Explorer (SFX)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-visualizing-your-cluster) is an open-source tool for inspecting and managing Azure Service Fabric clusters. Service Fabric Explorer is a desktop application for Windows, macOS and Linux.

Comment: the "Get-ServiceFabricClusterHealth" will get me only information about the application which are running on the Service Fabric cluster. The same is for the SF explorer. 

I'm a step before, I try to deploy the resource and want to get information about the resource. I don't have this explorer URL in the portal. It fails before and get no information why.

Answer (score 0):

After long research work I get my solution.

You can connect to you service fabric cluster nodes if they were created successfully. Use the public IP which you can find in the overview of the "VM scale set" and use Remote desktop connection (RDP) to connect to a VM.

How to set up this is described [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-remote-connect-to-azure-cluster-node.md)

Check the event log, check log in the Service fabric installation directory - it is on D:\SvcFab\Log\ check all directories for log.